# recursive creation of an unlimited 7-gon

Tags: algorithm, geometry

hey, i wondered if there's an algorithm to create a polygon, composed of triangles, to look like this:

http://homepages.wmich.edu/~drichter/images/mathieu/numberedvertices.jpg

the numbering of the vertices is not important, just the method how to get the points. notice that every point is connected to exactly 7 others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is [something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uniform_tiling_73-t2.png).

[image: heptagonal tiling]

It's an example of an [order-7 triangular tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-7_triangular_tiling) and closely related [heptagonal tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-3_heptagonal_tiling), which are in turn [hyperbolic tilings/tessellations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_tiling).  You can compute these to arbitrary resolution [as this video shows](http://vimeo.com/4154382). (you can take pairs of white and black triangles in the video to get the equilateral-like triangles in your picture)

The basic idea is to set up three circles that intersect at the appropriate angle -- 2π/7 in this case -- and then to reflect the triangle you get ad infinitum.  This is the basic construction behind Escher's famous [Circle Limit](http://www.mcescher.com/Gallery/recogn-bmp/LW436.jpg) pictures.

Let me know if you need more details.